# show hebrew words in a php response

Tags: php, response, hebrew

i am sending a JSON response through a php script which has some hebrew words.but when i run this script on browser it is showing '?' instead of hebrew characters..

FYI.. database is in hebrew_general_ci collation

any help would be appreciated..

thanks..

Comment: Did you verify that your browser, when displaying the '?' is set to Charset Windows-1255 (if you're using windows that is, any standard Hebrew encoding should work).
Is the response UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Answer (score 1):

you may not included appropriate CSS file. also charset variable is another problem while using native languages. use Utf-8 if you are using a unicode font
like

also problem may occur, if the created eot font is not good. i am not sure Hebrew need such font.

Comment: i am not using any CSS file.it is just a simple php script that is running on a LAMP server..it fetches some data(which contains both English and Hebrew words) from database and show it on the browser.(response is in JSON format)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the appropriate character set in your HTTP `Content-Type` header for the HTML page that will ultimately display the data contained in your JSON. Try adding this to the top of your php script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="windows-1255"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a content-type header, as others have suggested:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=YOUR_CHOSEN_CHARSET');
```

Try `charset=utf8`, or `charset=iso-8859-8`. There's a list of character sets [over here](http://a4esl.org/c/charset.html).

Comment: i hv tried both UTF-8 and iso-8859-8..but nothing happen..browser is displaying question marks..instead of hebrew characters..

Comment: Have you tried any other from the list supplied above?
Namely one of these:
Hebrew (DOS)
    ##charset=DOS-862 
Hebrew (ISO-Logical)
    ##charset=iso-8859-8-i 
Hebrew (ISO-Visual)
    ##charset=iso-8859-8 
Hebrew (Mac)
    ##charset=x-mac-hebrew 
Hebrew (Windows)
    ##charset=windows-1255